# Firebase Analytics UTM campaign tracking not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm not able to get UTM campaign tracking info in Firebase Analytics - Attribution - first_open. All my installs are shown as (direct)/(none).

I'm using both GA and Firebase Analytics and currently have a custom INSTALL_REFERRER receiver which calls CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive for GA. This works for GA and I can see all my campaigns.

The final merged manifest also does not have any other install referrer receiver. So obviously I'm probably missing a call to Firebase Analytics, but which one? Where is the documentation?

*Update 1*
This is the URL I'm using and it is tracked properly in GA.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app.package&referrer=utm_source%3Dapp%26utm_medium%3Dshare
```

Documentation for GA Android SDK recommends above format.

> Google Play Campaign Measurement allows you to see which campaigns and
>   traffic sources are sending users to download your app from the Google
>   Play Store. It is recommended that all developers implement Google
>   Play Store Campaign Measurement.

*Update 2*
Release notes for Firebase 9.6 seems to indicate this is fixed, but still not working as of Firebase 10.2.1

> Added tracking for the source of app install referrals when an app with Analytics is installed from the Play Store.

***Update 3***
Finally working as of Firebase 11.0.2. No changes to the URL.

Comment: I assume you are referring to Android SDK. Can you give more information like SDK version, and some debug log? If you can, may I ask for the URL params that you have? The SDK requires at least some utm_* params to log a campaign event.

Comment: I'm using both Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics. Campaign tracking is working for GA, so there apparently there is no issue with the URLs. I'm on Firebase Android SDK 9.4.0

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?

Comment: Still no resolution.

Answer (score 3):

There are two URL builder tools : One for [Google Analytics](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) and one for [Google Play](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder).  If you use the one for Google Analytics, UTM-based campaign tracking should work for you.

Comment: I've updated my post with the URL being used. The documentation for GA seems to recommend the Google Play format.

Comment: @steve-ganem, please guide on why google play URL builder will not work? and how to get campaign information using firebase analytics .. I'm getting it in Google Analytics.